# Shutdown ElasticSearch when running in daemon mode

Tags: elasticsearch, daemon

Ok, this is probably a pretty stupid question.
I started ElasticSearch in daemon mode on a server by running

```
./bin/elasticsearch -d
```

Unfortunately, this machine doesn't have curl (and it doesn't seem simple to install in this environment) so I can't run

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown'
```

I tried running this command from my local computer (substituting 'localhost' for the ip address) but it didn't seem to do anything

The terminal on the server is xterm-256color if that helps.

How do I shut it down?

Comment: what about `wget` or try `kill -9 $(pgrep elasticsearch)` ?

Comment: sorry, I'm not very familiar with the terminal. the command you said didn't work though. It says -9 is not valid. Also, wget using "wget 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown'" said it was a bad request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will give you the #PID for port running 9200

`lsof -i :9200`

once you get that #PID, kill it with

`kill -9 #PID`